# Python packages not getting imported after installing Anaconda

Tags: python, opencv

After setting up Anaconda according to the setup instructions, I tried to run python in cmd and then

```
import pandas as pd
```

I also tried the following commands to check

```
where python
where conda
```

C:\Users\aashi\anaconda3\python.exe

C:\Users\aashi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

C:\Users\aashi\anaconda3\condabin\conda.bat

C:\Users\aashi\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe

C:\Users\aashi\anaconda3\Library\bin\conda.bat

Python works properly, but after typing
import pandas as pd
or
import numpy as np

I got the error
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

However, when I run the same commands in Anaconda prompt, it works fine.

Comment: you have to run, inside the anaconda directory . in your case its in C:\Users\aashi\anaconda3 . Try to launch your scripts from here, it should run. for running it from command line without path dependencies> add the required path in Environment variables .

Answer (score 0):

First Option: Try to install the package in the conda env(Virtual Environment which is automatically created.)

Second Option: You can install the module through Anaconda Prompt.

Third Option:

conda create --name myenv
When conda ask for Proceed? Type 'y'
activate myenv
conda install numpy